# Extract lower number over a fixated threshold?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I ask for your help because I'm going crazy.

I have this procedure that takes from my main a struct called lista(of a typedefined TipoL) that is composed by an int (N, numbers of chars inserted) and an array of lowercase chars(seqchar). I need the procedure to printf the lowest number over an user-inserted threshold.
I would like to know why this doesn't work rather than having another way to do this because now I feel like I'm doing something wrong since the last printf gives this output, assuming an example of d being the threshold: The smallest character over the threshold ('d') (ASCII '100') is 'nothing here' (ASCII '0') and I don't know why.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

```
void Minimum(TipoL lista)
{
int i,j;
char k,s,THRESHOLD,ArrTHRESHOLD[lista.N];


    scanf("%c", &THRESHOLD);

    for(i=0; i<lista.N; i++)
    {
        if(lista.seqchar[i]>THRESHOLD)
        {
        ArrTHRESHOLD[i]=lista.seqchar[i];
        }
    }

    s=ArrTHRESHOLD[0];
    for(j=1; j<lista.N; j++)
    {
        if(ArrTHRESHOLD[j]<s)
        {
        s=ArrTHRESHOLD[j];
        }
    }
printf("\nThe smallest character over the threshold '%c' (ASCII '%d') is: '%c'\n(ASCII '%d')\n", THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD, s, s);
}
```

}

Comment: What are `Soglia` and `ArrSoglia`?

Comment: What is `TipoL` (its definition)? Why have you not used `TRESHOLD` after inputting a value?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to replace every italian declaration with english, now its perfected. TipoL is the globally-declared name of the struct used.

Comment: It will be perfect when you show the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which means verifiable by *you too*. Now nobody knows whether you have posted the truth after making grand changes to the posted code.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is uninitialized.

Comment: I can't pass the Whole code since it's about 150 lines of code but im 100% sure the problem is here because every part of the other functions works perfectly. I just can't understand what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Is this as simple as adding a space `scanf("%c", &TRESHOLD);` --> `scanf(" %c", &TRESHOLD);`?

Comment: Nope that wasnt the problem, its been solved by the two guys under this post. Thank you anyway for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do the following:

```
if(lista.seqchar[i]>THRESHOLD)
{
    ArrTHRESHOLD[i]=lista.seqchar[i];
}
```

you are missing the `else` case, so you leave `ArrTHRESHOLD[i]` un-initialized. You should instead set it to some `maximum value` in order to avoid it being selected in the next phase:

```
else
{
    ArrTHRESHOLD[i]= 127; // or MAX_CHAR;
}
```

Sure, there is better than this method but since you asked help to make your method work, I hope this helps.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much now it works and i understood what i was doing wrong . very much appreciated!!

Comment: @RuggeroLatella You are welcome, and I appreciated the fact that your main goal was to understand what's wrong and to continue with your own work. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know why this doesnt work rather than having another way to do this

`ArrTHRESHOLD` has automatic duration and no initializer, so all its elements are initially indeterminate.  You scan the input array, and copy those elements exceeding the threshold to *the corresponding element* of `ArrTHRESHOLD`, leaving the other elements indeterminate.
You then scan `ArrTHRESHOLD`, including the indeterminate elements, to attempt to identify the minimum.
Using indeterminate values produces undefined behavior.

You could consider keeping a separate count of the number of elements so far copied into `ArrTHRESHOLD`, and using that to fill an initial subset of the elements, without gaps.  Afterward, you could scan just those elements as you now do.

Better, however, would be to do without `ArrTHRESHOLD` altogether: you don't need it, as you can do everything necessary in your pass through `lista.seqchar`.

Comment: thank you verymuch for your help too! now i got a better and cleaner idea on how to do it. ill try your method too!